# How do C++ HTTPS libraries compare in terms of performance (e.g. memory footprint, CPU time, etc?)

Tags: c++, networking

I've seen several posts stating that one networking library is better than another because of functionality or ease of use, but I haven't seen anything related to performance.  I've checked all over Google and I can't find any comparisons.

I am starting a networking project soon and I would like to use either Poco or libCurl.  I am interested in the lightI was originally planning to use Boost.ASIO, but it doesn't have an HTTPS client implementation. It does have a sample HTTPS client implemented in Boost.ASIO, but not an actual protocol handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It does not matter. The bottleneck is almost certainly going to be the network media, or whatever processing you're doing on top of the HTTPS connection. SSL is cheap in terms of CPU time. (Unfortunately it's not cheap in terms of network latency but the library performance does not matter there).
2. Performance is always a series of tradeoffs. The only way you're going to know which library performs best for you is to try a few of them. Most likely, you'll see negligible differences.

Comment: Thanks. On a different note, when a fellow engineer asks which networking library is the *lightest*, what do you think he is referring to? I thought it might be memory footprint or performance.

Comment: @Jamaal: Generally, I would think binary size.

Answer (score 1):

If you want https support, you have better to use libcurl. libcurl support https and http over proxy, https over proxy. If you want support proxy, you should only set HTTP_PROXY environment variable.

Curl provide fwrite like callbacks to write datas to your buffers.

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

typedef struct {
    char* data;     // response data from server
    size_t size;    // response size of data
} MEMFILE;

MEMFILE*
memfopen() {
    MEMFILE* mf = (MEMFILE*) malloc(sizeof(MEMFILE));
    if (mf) {
        mf->data = NULL;
        mf->size = 0;
    }
    return mf;
}

void
memfclose(MEMFILE* mf) {
    if (mf->data) free(mf->data);
    free(mf);
}

size_t
memfwrite(char* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* stream) {
    MEMFILE* mf = (MEMFILE*) stream;
    int block = size * nmemb;
    if (!mf) return block; // through
    if (!mf->data)
        mf->data = (char*) malloc(block);
    else
        mf->data = (char*) realloc(mf->data, mf->size + block);
    if (mf->data) {
        memcpy(mf->data + mf->size, ptr, block);
        mf->size += block;
    }
    return block;
}

char*
memfstrdup(MEMFILE* mf) {
    char* buf;
    if (mf->size == 0) return NULL;
    buf = (char*) malloc(mf->size + 1);
    memcpy(buf, mf->data, mf->size);
    buf[mf->size] = 0;
    return buf;
}

int main() {
    CURL* curl;
    MEMFILE* mf;
    char* ptr;

    mf = memfopen();
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://github.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, mf);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, memfwrite);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    ptr = memfstrdup(mf);
    printf("%s\n", ptr);
    free(ptr);

    memfclose(mf);
}
```